# How do I perform Type Conversion in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

How do I convert Symbol to String, Integer to Float, and other similar type conversions in Clojure?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You tell the compiler what type you want something to be by adding metadata to it.
This can make some operations faster and help eliminate reflection. The `^`symbol is syntactic sugar for add this to the metadata for whatever comes next.

```
(defn my-function  [^String my-string] ....
```

Symbol to string:

```
(str 'my-symbol)
```

For numbers, use the name of the type as a function name:

```
(int 4922354)
(double 42)
(byte 254)
(char 20)
etc...
```

For more info: http://clojure.org/java_interop#toc35